# How to change access callback for content create?

Tags: 7, routes, users

I want to allow each user to create a specific node type only once.I know that I must use hook_menu_alter and change *access callback* to my own callback function.But using this way Drupal's main access callback is overriden and it will skip permissions defined in permissions page.

Is there a way to call my own access callback after main access callback is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $content_type = 'the machine name for the content type for which you want to alter the access callback';
  $type_url_str = str_replace('_', '-', $content_type);

  if (isset($items['node/add/' . $type_url_str])) {
    array_unshift($items['node/add/' . $type_url_str]['access arguments'], $items['node/add/' . $type_url_str]['access callback']);
    $items['node/add/' . $type_url_str]['access callback'] = 'mymodule_node_access';
  }
}

function mymodule_node_access() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $callback = array_shift($args);
  $result = call_user_func_array($callback, $args);

  // ...
}
```

The new access callback invokes the old access callback passing the arguments it is expecting; it can verify the result returned by the old access callback, and decide the next step to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Just replace original access callback with your own function, and then in your function do both your checks AND call the original callback function.